# Cannot print from Kate 3.14.13 on Ubuntu 14.04LTS

Tags: printing, ubuntu-14.04, kate

I have Kate 3.14.13 and Konsole 2.13.2 (based on KDE 4.14.13) installed on Ubuntu 14.04LTS. Kate works great, as do the various plugsins I have installed, however, I cannot print.

If I go to File-> Print, the screen darkens and then Kate locks up and I must force quit.

In the terminal from which I ran Kate (Gnome Terminal 3.6.2) I get an error message:

```
uint DBusMenuExporterDBus::GetLayout(int, int, const QStringList&, 
DBusMenuLayoutItem&): Condition failed: menu
```

I tried running Kate from Konsole instead, and the same behavior occurs, although the error message is slightly different:

```
QDBusConnection: session D-Bus connection created before QCoreApplication. 
Application may misbehave.
```

I tried Googling both error messages, but did not find anything immediately helpful. I'm a Unix n00b, and do not always understand the more technical bug reports that come up when searching error messages.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

OK, so it turns out that the default printer my settings -> printer menu somehow got set to some generic laserjet printer (maybe during a core update?) that I am not even sure exists on our network here at work,

When I connected to the printer just down the hall from me, and selected an appropriate driver, Kate was able to print.

I should have checked this first, but I was happily printing from other programs last week, so I did not printer setup would be an issue.